# Function in Sprite does not run to display

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Function X1 simply does not run- no trace result and programme so basic.
Board.as is called- I checked.
Simple sprite display not working.

Main.as

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import Start;
    import Board;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Michael
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init():void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var Board1:Sprite = new Board();   
            stage.addChild(Board1);


            Board1.visible = true;

            var Start1:Sprite = new Start();
            Start1.x = 32;
            Start1.y = 32;
            addChild (Start1);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
            function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if (e.keyCode ==Keyboard.SPACE) 
            {
            removeChild(Start1);
            Start1 = null;  
            }


            } 
}
```

Board.as

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;


    /**
     * ...
     * @author Michael
     */
    public class Board extends Sprite
    {
    [Embed(source="../lib/Board.jpg")]
    private var BoardClass :Class

    public function X1():void  
    {
        var boardclass:Bitmap = new BoardClass () as Bitmap;
    trace("Project is running fine!");
        this.addChild(boardclass);

    }
    }



}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually calling the method from anywhere.  Do the following in your Main class after instantiating the class: Board1.X1();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function X1(). Change the code part in your Main.as class where you create the Board to this:

```
var Board1:Sprite = new Board(); 
Board1.X1();
stage.addChild(Board1);
```

A few more tips for your code:

1) You don't need  `Board1.visible = true;`, it's visible by default

2) Change the name of Board1 to board1 or just board. It's a standard to call classes with first capital letter.

**EDIT:**

If you want X1() to be run as you create the object, call this function in the constructor of Board.as. Constructor is a function that is run when you create an object. For Board.as it would be like this:

```
public function Board():void
{

   X1(); // this function will be called when you create a new Board object
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way this Sprite does almost nothing but display the image and be an object to collide with. The visible stuff is just fiddling to try get something to work.

Comment: Getting closer to right- its processing but no image- its a 277 KB JPG image- is that too big to load fast?

Comment: Darn- I accidentally commented out the AddChild to Stage.